# Spring Boot 2 / Kotlin / JDK9 - Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.transaction.SystemException

Tags: hibernate, maven, spring-boot, kotlin, java-9

actually I'm developing a Spring Boot v2 application using Kotlin. I'm using JDK in version 9.

After adding the dependency `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` I'm getting ClassNotFound Errors:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/SystemException

I have found some articles for that problem and have add under /src/main/kotlin a `module-info.java` with following content:

```
    module de.sample.backend {

//    requires java.xml.bind;
    requires javax.transaction.api;
//    requires validation.api;
    requires hibernate.jpa;
//    requires hibernate.validator;
    requires spring.beans;
    requires spring.core;
    requires spring.context;
    requires spring.tx;
    requires spring.web;
    requires spring.webmvc;
    requires spring.data.commons;
    requires spring.data.jpa;
    requires spring.boot;
    requires spring.boot.autoconfigure;
//    requires cache.api;

}
```

But then I will get an `Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 32800`

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile
>   (default-compile) on project naehmeisterei-services: Execution
>   default-compile of goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile failed:
>   32800 -> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
>   execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile
>   (default-compile) on project naehmeisterei-services: Execution
>   default-compile of goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile failed:
>   32800
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
>   (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
>   (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build
>   (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
>       at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
>       at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced
>   (Launcher.java:289)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode
>   (Launcher.java:415)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356) Caused by:
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution
>   default-compile of goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile failed:
>   32800

Here is my complete pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>de.sample.backend</groupId>
    <artifactId>sample-services</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>sample-services</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <!--<java.version>1.8</java.version>-->
        <maven.compiler.source>1.9</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.9</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.release>9</maven.compiler.release>
        <kotlin.version>1.2.20</kotlin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Camunda - Spring Boot -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-webapp</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Spring Boot -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://jaxenter.de/spring-boot-2-actuator-2-0-68749 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Kotlin -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JUnit -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Persistence / Database -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Firebase -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <configuration>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                    </args>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <plugin>spring</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Implementation-Version>${project.version}</Implementation-Version>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>9</source>
                    <target>9</target>
                    <jdkToolchain>
                        <version>9</version>
                    </jdkToolchain>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

I actually don't know how to solve that problem. On another computer with JDK 8 it compiles fine.

Can somebody help?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I have created a new spring-boot project using the spring initialzr:
https://github.com/Chris81T/spring-boot-jdk9-kotlin-demo

Without any changes I will get the same error. Perhaps someone can look for it to get it working. That would be nice :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include all javaee dependencies that are deprecated from Java 9 (alternative is to add `--add-modules java.se.ee` or `--add-modules ALL-SYSTEM` to the maven compiler options and to java starting the application but it is not recommended, because classes will be gone in Java 11).

1.You need to remove the module-info.java file and add the dependencies below.

2. Add a properties in maven (because surefire/failsafe 2.20.1 has a [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1424) that prevents correct running of the tests in Java 9):

> ```
> <properties>                                                                
>     <argLine>--add-modules java.base</argLine>
>  </properties>
> ```

or you can switch to surefire 2.21.0 - see http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/java9.html

Here's I think complete list, you can pick and choose or just use all of them:

```
    <dependency>                                                                                                                                                         
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>                               
        <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>                               
        <version>2.3.0</version>                                            
    </dependency>                                                           
    <dependency>                                                            
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>                               
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>                                  
        <version>2.3.0</version>                                            
    </dependency>                                                           
    <dependency>                                                            
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>                                   
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>                                   
        <version>2.3.0</version>                                            
    </dependency>                                                           
    <dependency>                                                            
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>                                 
        <artifactId>javax.activation-api</artifactId>                       
        <version>1.2.0</version>                                            
    </dependency>                                                           
    <dependency>                                                            
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>                                 
        <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>                       
        <version>1.3.1</version>                                            
    </dependency>                                                           
    <dependency>                                                            
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>                                
        <artifactId>javax.transaction-api</artifactId>                      
        <version>1.2</version>                                              
    </dependency>                                                           
    <dependency>                                                            
        <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>                                     
        <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>                                  
        <version>2.3.0</version>                                            
    </dependency>                                                           
    <dependency>                                                            
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>                                   
        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>                                   
        <version>2.3.0</version>                                            
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Hi Krzysztof Krasoń,
thank you for your answer. Why ever including your list of dependencies or using the add-modules options didn't work for me. Actually I have created with the spring initializr (https://start.spring.io/) a new demo project and have select the modul like "jpa". Without adding any code or change something I will get the same error. I will push the demo to my github and provide a link in my post.

Comment: @Chris81T Did you remove the module-info.java file?

Comment: Yes, I have removed it. But then I get the ClassNotFound Error again. Here is a simple demo project, that will show the error:
https://github.com/Chris81T/spring-boot-jdk9-kotlin-demo

Comment: @Chris81T I've added one more crucial thing for the tests to work in the answer

Comment: thank you for your help! Using the surefire in version 2.21.0 and adding the dependency "jaxb-runtime" did it for me. Thanks!